# counting desc in hive mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hiveql

I have a table in hive which consists of

```
questionid,questiontag,answerID,userIDofanswerer
```

I need Top 10 most commonly used tags in this data set.

I tried :

```
select count(questionID),questiontag from table GROUP BY tags;
```

but how do I order it by `Count(questionID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query below `ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 10` will select top 10  most commonly used tags:

```
    SELECT count(questionID) cnt ,
           questiontag 
      FROM table 
  GROUP BY questiontag 
  ORDER BY cnt DESC 
  LIMIT 10;
```

`count(*)` will count all rows including NULL questionID

`count(questionID)` will count only rows where questionID is not NULL

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
select count(questionID) as cnt,questiontag from table GROUP BY questiontag
order by cnt desc limit 10;
```